# Disable a div for mobile screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I upgraded from bootstrap 2.0 to 3.0.  I have this slider that refreshes itself in every animation so it gets in the way of the top mobile menu when you click it.  I tried Display: none;, and it doesn't show, but because it still is running it gets in the way of the mobile nav bar.  How can I disable the div or make it not load on a smaller screen? Would it be a JQuery command?

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 767px) {    #hiddenslider{
  display:none;
}
}

</style>

<!-- start: Slider -->
<div class="slider-wrapper" ID="hiddenslider">

    <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
        <div class="da-slide">
            <h2>Certified Techs </h2>
            <p>Text in Here</p>
            <a href="about.html" class="da-link">Read more</a>
            <div class="da-img"><img class='img-responsive'  src="img/parallax-slider/twitter.png" alt="image01" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="da-slide">
            <h2>Is your Computer Slow?</h2>
            <p>Text in here</p>
            <a href="about.html" class="da-link">Read more</a>
            <div class="da-img"><img class='img-responsive' src="img/parallax-slider/responsive.png" alt="image02" /></div>
        </div>

        <nav class="da-arrows">
            <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
            <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
        </nav>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- end: Slider -->
```

Comment: You're missing a `}` in your CSS. You need a `{}` pair for `@media (max-width: 767px)` and a `{}` pair for `#hiddenslider`.

Comment: Is there anything else? It hides it, but is there a way to disable it?

Comment: If it isn't being displayed, how is it getting in the way of the mobile nav bar?

Answer (score 2):

You can use bootstraps "hidden" classes as well: `hidden-xs` for extra small devices. For example:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper hidden-xs" ID="hiddenslider">
```

Comment: <div class="slider-wrapper hidden-xs" ID="hiddenslider">

Comment: Thanks DavidG. Will include an example next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the element with `jQuery` `.remove(`) method which removes the element from the `DOM`. You can also set when you want the element removed.

```
if ($(window).width() <= 768) { // Set when you want it removed

 $("the-element").remove();

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this, especially on a device that has a resolution of 1024x768 as it means rotating it will mean it's not visible when it should be.

Comment: That is why I suggest setting when he wants it removed.

Comment: The main point is that this is really not needed. OPs code is either working correctly or there is an external factor not shown here. A simple media query (or using the Bootstrap classes) is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
<style>
/*
@media (max-width: 767px) {    #hiddenslider{
  display:none;
}
}
*/
</style>

<!-- start: Slider -->
<div class="slider-wrapper hidden-sm hidden-xs" ID="hiddenslider">
```

That's all there is to it.  Let Bootstrap handle everything.  There's no need to come with your own CSS to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: none;` merely hides the element from view and does not remove it from the DOM flow.

Use `visibility: none;` to achieve what you want.

You can use pure CSS to change this via media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #hiddenslider {
        visibility: none;
    }
}
```